# Bfill on Groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

| index | Group | rank | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 2 | 344.0 |
| 1 | a | 3 | NaN |
| 2 | b | 1 | 455.0 |
| 3 | a | 1 | NaN |
| 4 | b | 2 | NaN |

I want to group data by 'Group', then sort according to 'rank' and then bfill only for rank == 1. The dataset is very big so I want to avoid loops.

I tried

`temp[temp['rank']<=2].sort_values('rank', ascending = True).groupby('Group').bfill(axis='rows', inplace = True)`

but this gives me
"backfill() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove non exist parameters `axis='rows', inplace = True` in [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html) and assign back to filtered rows:

```
m = temp['rank']<=2
temp.loc[m, 'Values'] = temp[m].sort_values('rank').groupby('Group')['Values'].bfill()
```

Comment: can you say why the parameters dont work? here these parameters are listed https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html

Comment: @paka - because use [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html)

Answer (score 0):

df.sort_values(by = 'rank', inplace = True)

df = df.assign(Values1 = lambda x: x['rank'] == 1).fillna(method = 'bfill')

df.groupby(by = 'Group')['Values']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).